# SQL Server 2005 Performance and white space

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance

I have been told and I'm not sure I believe this: Removing white space from my stored procedures in sql server 2005, before I submit them, will make them run faster and improve  performance. I am wondering what everyone else thinks?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without benchmarking it, I can't "know" but that sounds like bull.

Firstly, I'm pretty sure SQLServer compiles stored procedures (meaning, absolutely nothing in the verbosity effects it).  Secondly, parsing whitespace is time-trivial in any system.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how this would be the case. Perhaps the stored procedure would compile slightly faster, but after that it shouldn't make any difference whatsoever.

More importantly, even if this were true, I can't imagine the time spent removing whitespace would be worth whatever performance benefit you'd get.

Answer (score 1):

I call shenanigans. This doesn't even pass the smell test. sprocs get compiled, what SQL Server works with is a plan created from your sproc - the white space is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  It turns out that you can have two queries, identical except for white space, that run at different speeds on SQL Server.  I would not have believed this had I not seen it with my own eyes, however this did come up for me at work (on sql server 2008) and after much testing, pulling of hair and denial I had to admit it was happening.   Here's an example of another person experiencing the same problem:

[Space in SQL Server 2008 R2 slows down performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363970/space-in-sql-server-2008-r2-slows-down-performance)

Now for the "no" part of the answer. We have a lot of queries with a lot of white space and this has happened exactly once that I'm aware of.  It's not at all a standard way to speed up queries, it just happens that there is a really odd edge case.  I wouldn't spend any time removing white space from stored procedures, it's almost never going to help.  Almost.